# KVM switch vs. multiple V switches plus KM switch

Tags: hdmi, switch, displayport, kvm-switch

I have noticed that KVM switches are usually expensive, limited in the choice of video interface such as having only one of either only HDMI or DP rather than both and being limited in the number of USB ports.

What's the advantage over a setup of multiple video switches where you have a HDMI/DP switch for each monitor and could buy the switch according to the sample rate and resolution of the monitor in question, and a USB/KM switch which is cheap and usually offers at least 4 ports?

The latter is potentially cheaper and can be chosen more flexibly with regard to the specifications of the devices that are going to be connected.

Edit: This is not a question about "opinion", I am trying to understand wether there is an inherent technical advantage to the KVM switch solution that I am missing.